# Zip network requests via Kotlin Coroutine Flow

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have a code which zips two network requests via RxJava:

```
Single.zip(repository.requestDate(), repository.requestTime()) {
  date, time -> Result(date, time)
}
```

it means that `repository.requestDate()`/`repository.requestTime()` returns `Single<T>`

If I want to use Coroutines I need to change requests to:

```
@GET('link/date')
suspend fun requestDate() : Date

@GET('link/time')
suspend fun requestTime() : Time
```

But, **How can I zip requests via Flow from Kotlin Coroutines?**

I know that I can do it like this:

```
coroutineScope {
   val date = repository.requestDate()
   val time = repository.requestTime()
   Result(date, time)
}
```

**But I want to do it via Flow!**

I know about Channels, but `Channels.zip()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
val dateFlow = flowOf(repository.requestDate())
val timeFlow = flowOf(repository.requestTime())
val zippedFlow = dateFlow.zip(timeFlow) { date, time -> Result(date, time) }
```

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html

Comment: Please don't use this. The requestDate() and requestTime() suspending functions will be executed sequentially, then the flows will be created and then the zip happens, which is completely pointless at this point because you want to execute both the tasks in parallel. Change the calls flowOf(suspendingFunction()) to flow { emit(suspendingFunction()) } to achieve the parallel execution

Answer (score 7):

For most operations `Flow` follows the same rules as normal co-routines, so to zip two separate requests you need to apply the [async concurrency pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#concurrent-using-async).

In practise this will end up looking like this:

```
flow {
    emit(coroutineScope/withContext(SomeDispatcher) {
        val date = async { repository.requestDate() }
        val time = async { repository.requestTime() }
        Result(date.await(), time.await())
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that Flow Coroutines can replace popular RX operators, but it is doesn't look succinctly. Maybe, it is better to use Channels for the task? How do you think?

Comment: @kiskae What is "Result" here?

Comment: The code is a direct translation of the OPs original RxJava code, so its a class provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` or `combine` operator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).