# how to make only one side to be observed in android studio/kotlin/observer/

Tags: android, kotlin

Now, regardless of pageNum, definitely observing both sides(userRecent/userSaved)

this is Fragment

```
        overViewModel.userResent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { userlist ->
            userlist?.apply {
                val pageNum = arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)
                if (pageNum == 1) {
                    viewModelAdapter?.data = userlist
                }
            }
        })

        overViewModel.userSaved.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { userlist ->
            userlist?.apply {
                val pageNum = arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)
                if (pageNum == 2) {
                    viewModelAdapter?.data = userlist
                }
            }
        })
```

How do I code so that only one side is observed?
<Currently, both userRecent and userSaved are using observe, and I am thinking about how to combine them into one.>

Comment: Which library do you use ? For example Coroutine or Rxjava ?

Comment: for rx java, you can look zip operation. If you are using coroutine, you could use kotlin flow zip operation. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622619/zip-network-requests-via-kotlin-coroutine-flow

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You're observing two different pieces of data, and when one of them changes you do a thing with it depending on the current section number. When you say you want that "only one side is observed" it sounds like you want to delete one of them?

Comment: @cactustictacs Sorry, my English is not good!

I'm using coroutine right now.

Currently, both userRecent and userSaved are using observe, and I am thinking about how to combine them into one.

Comment: ``userResent`` (you might mean ``Recent``) and ``userSaved`` are separate data items. When you ``observe`` them, you're providing some code that needs to run when the value of that data changes. We don't know how ``userResent`` and ``userSaved`` relate to each other, so we can't help you decide if they can be combined into one observable piece of data. There's at least something different about them, since you're reacting to each one differently (checking the page number). If you just want to avoid the repetition, you could make a function like ``fun setAdapterData(userlist, requiredPageNum)``